# FlatList não renderiza os dados ao iniciar o Aplicativo - Integração com Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

Boa tarde galera, estava estudando a biblioteca React Native Firebase a fim de aprender a trabalhar com uma integração do Firebase com React Native. Porém, estou enfrentando alguns problemas, **o objetivo é adicionar os dados no Realtime Database por meio de uma tela e depois pegar os dados armazenados no banco de dados para apresentar na tela Home utilizando uma FlatList (algo que deveria ser simples)**, mas o grande o problema é que o aplicativo não renderiza os dados já armazenados quando é aberto pela primeira vez, ou seja quando inicia o App. Os dados são renderizados pela FlatList somente quando navego para a tela de adição e adiciono um novo item no banco de dados (assim ele renderiza os recém adicionados e os já existentes) ou quando realizo um "Refresh" no App (Dando um CTRL+S na IDE ou recarregando o App no emulador). Na tentativa de solucionar o problema fiz alguns testes e pelo que percebi **A FlatList pega os dados armazenados na state quando ainda esta vazia, ou seja não recebeu os dados do firebase ainda, mesmo já tendo feito a requisição**. Tentei utilizar funções assíncronas para tentar resolver, mas sem sucesso, assim, resolvi recorrer a vocês, vou disponibilizar o código mais básico que fiz (o que na minha concepção deveria funcionar). Já rodei o App no meu dispositivo físico, acreditando que fosse um problema do emulador, mas o problema persistiu. Segue o código utilizado originalmente:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';  
import styled from 'styled-components/native';

import database from '@react-native-firebase/database';

const Container = styled.SafeAreaView`
    flex:1;
    justify-content:center;
`;

const Texto = styled.Text`
    margin:20px;
`;

const Lista = styled.FlatList``;

const Botao = styled.Button`

`;

const HomeScreen = (props) => {

    const [vetor, setVetor] = useState([])

    database().ref('users').on('value', (snapshot) => {

        snapshot.forEach((childItem)=>{

            vetor.push({
                name:childItem.val().name,
                idade:childItem.val().idade
            })
        })

        setVetor(vetor)
    })

    const mudarTela = () => {
        props.navigation.reset({
            routes:[{name:'Tela2'}]
        })
    }

    return (
        <Container>
           <Lista data={vetor} renderItem={({item})=><Texto>{item.name} idade: {item.idade}</Texto>}/>
            <Botao title='Tela de Adição' onPress={()=>mudarTela()} />
        </Container>
    );
}

export default HomeScreen;
```

Cabe ressaltar que sou novo na FrameWork e este é um dos meus primeiros post's aqui, portanto perdoem algum erro que eu tenha cometido.

Answer (score 1):

Tenta assim.

useEffect(() => {
database().ref('users').on('value', (snapshot) => {

setVetor(snapshot)

```
})
}, [])
```

quando vc usar o flatList vc puxa o vetor, deve conter um array la dentro com as informações que vc precisa, puxa no console pra testar.
Em seguida o componente que vc usar no render do Flatlist vc mapeie com
...data é o indice que vc vai apontar para os objetos do arra..
data.val().name,
data.val().idade,

Answer (score 0):

Tem um problema no seu código, não sei se vai resolver o problema:

O estado `vetor` é imutável, e só deve ser modificado pela função `setVetor`. Você está dando um `push` em `vetor` o que parece não fazer efeito.

Nesse sentido, crie uma variável temporária para armazenar o resultado, e depois atualize o resultado no final. Algo assim,

```js
database()
  .ref('users')
  .on('value', (snapshot) => {
    const data = [];
    snapshot.forEach((childItem) => {
      data.push({
        name: childItem.val().name,
        idade: childItem.val().idade,
      });
    });

    setVetor(data);
  });
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Pedro Henrique, irei testar. Mas consegui resolver o problema re-criando o componente utilizando classes ao invés de função e React Hooks. Mantive a mesma lógica, fiz apenas as devidas alterações no componente para funcionar com classes e funcionou prefeitamente.